# Reference to a element inside a grid in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a function which querys the database for Strings (which are x:Name="" in my application)

Following is the code:

```
 Try
            For Each s In output
                Dim nameOfControl = s
                Dim window = Windows.Application.Current.Windows(0)
                Dim visuals = GetVisualChildren(Of FrameworkElement)(window)
                Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
                child.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            Next


 Public Iterator Function GetVisualChildren(Of T As Visual)(parent As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim child As T = Nothing
    Dim numVisuals As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
    For i As Integer = 0 To numVisuals - 1
        Dim v As Visual = DirectCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i), Visual)
        child = TryCast(v, T)
        If v IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each item In GetVisualChildren(Of T)(v)
                Yield item
            Next
        End If
        If child IsNot Nothing Then
            Yield child
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this does not work for all elements, ie. my window consists of a `TabControl` which i can call by "x name", same goes for `toolBar`, everything works well even with `TabItem's` but i cannot reference to  `<Button x:Name="buttonRefresh"` which is inside one of `TabItem's` grids.

I recieve a error NullReferenceException on line bellow:

> child.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

If i insert a breakpoint at that line i get this `{System.Windows.Controls.TabItem Header:FirstTab Content:}` for `child` so i'm asuming i need to change something about this piece of code

> Dim window = Windows.Application.Current.Windows(0)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
```

The `FirstOrDefault` method will return `Nothing` if the predicate results in `False`.  In your case, it has done so because on the next line, `child` is null, hence the NRE:

```
child.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

You can't assign to the `Visibility` property on `child` because it's `Nothing`.

Your predicate is `Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl`, so there must not be a value in the collection returned by `visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)()` whose `Name` property equals `nameOfControl`.

To address this, you need to debug it and see what's really going on.  I would break your statement into two lines:

```
Dim child = visuals.OfType(Of FrameworkElement)()
Dim match = child.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameOfControl)
```

Put a break point on the second line so it breaks before that statement runs.  Then look in your locals/autos window (assuming Visual Studio), and see what's actually in the collection.

One other thing to note here: when you compare `x.Name` to `nameOfControl` with the equals sign `=`, it does so in **case sensitive** manner, so if you have `MyName` and `myname`, those two are *not* equal.  You can use this instead if you want it to be compare in a case-insensitive manner:

```
Function(x) x.Name.Equals(nameOfControl, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: So, is there anything I can do in this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, the match returns a value for all tabs `{System.Windows.Controls.TabItem Header:Tab Two Content:}` **Tab Two or Tab Three**. But for nameOfControl "refreshButton"  i get Nothing in **match**